# Is it possible to add Shipping Method to Android Pay default screen?

Tags: android-pay, applepay

[Apple Pay allows customizable fields on default confirmation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2hSq.png)

Does Android Pay allow these fields to be customized/added to it?